# Get values inside quotes from a string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have a string something like this:

```
<BU Name="xyz" SerialNo="3838383" impression="jdhfl87lkjh8937ljk" />
```

I want to extract values like this:

Name = xyz
SerialNo = 3838383
impression = jdhfl87lkjh8937ljk

How to get these values in C#?

I am using C# 3.5.

Comment: Use something like LINQ to XML, parse it as an `XElement`, and then use the `Attribute` method to fetch each an attritbute as an `XAttribute`. You can then cast from that to the relevant types, e.g. `int` for `SerialNo` and `string` for the other two. How much of that have you already tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried using .contains and searching for Name, but not following how to read the value of Name. Please illustrate.

Comment: No, please do some research - I've given you the basic outline here. You've got XML - so use an XML parser. Hint: `XElement.Parse`...

Comment: @JonSkeet So first I need to convert it into XML and then parse XElement?

Comment: It's already XML. You can just parse it into an `XElement` using `XElement element = XElement.Parse(yourVariable);`

Comment: @JonSkeet OK Thanks. I am trying...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am able to get element if it is a valid XML. In case there is any error in the XML it crashes. Is there any way other than XML with which I can search and pick only specific values like Name and SerialNo which is valid in most of the strings?

Comment: Well is this meant to be XML or not? Where do you get the data from? Are values going to be XML-escaped? Your question is really unclear on this front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by some reason you don't want to use Xml parser you can use reqular expression to achieve this.

Use this regular expression:

```
(\w)+=\"(\w)+\"
```

Use this regular expression like this:

```
   var input = @"<BU Name=""xyz"" SerialNo=""3838383"" impression=""jdhfl87lkjh8937ljk"" />";
   var pattern = @"(\w)+=\""(\w)+\""";
   var result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
   foreach (var match in result.Cast<Match>())
   {
       Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
   }
```

**Result:**

```
//Name="xyz"
//SerialNo="3838383"
//impression="jdhfl87lkjh8937ljk"
//Press any key to continue.
```